# Define global constant in Matlab

Tags: matlab, namespaces, global-variables, constants, superglobals

I want to define SI global prefixes in Matlab to make my code self explaining.

I defined it in `startup.m`:

```
% define SI prefix
global SI
SI.milli = 1e-3;
SI.micro = 1e-6;
% and so on..
```

It works fine, if I run `test.m` directly

```
% test.m file
Area = 10 * SI.micro * 4 * SI.milli % m^2
```

But it fails in external functions. How can I make `SI` visible in the name space of external functions too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts share the caller variable scope. Inside a function you need to write `global SI` as well.